# Access table that will link to a table on SQL Server, update when Access Data changes

Tags: sql-server, excel, ms-access, azure-sql-database

I have an Access Database, which links in multiple Excel files as well as being connected to Google Analytics.

I created a Unison Query to bring all the files and tables into one Table.

I need this table to be accessible and refreshable by multiple other users, normally through an excel powerpivot table. I set up an Azure SQL server and did the export wizard to move the data over, which works but I cannot update it with new data (which I need to do daily). Simply sharing the access db won't work as not everyone has same file structures.

How can I get the table in Access to link to SQL, so when it is updated in Access, the table in SQL updates?

Comment: I would go a different way. Create a linked table in Access and keep all the data in one location. Then your data is always up to date.

Comment: But I need to be able to update the data in excel due to formulas that extract information out of the data?

Comment: Set up an MS Access app that links Excel AND SQL Server. Then, run append query(ies) to migrate Excel linked tables to SQL Server linked table.

Comment: @Parfait do you have link with more information on this? This sounds like a great solution, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After exporting table manually to Azure SQL Server, simply link that very table into the MS Access application and then run action queries manually or automatically via code for your daily update.

1. [Linked SQL Server Table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/import-or-link-to-data-in-an-sql-server-database-a5a3b4eb-57b9-45a0-b732-77bc6089b84e)

   This is a well-known feature of MSAccess.exe, capable of connecting to practically any ODBC/OLEBD compliant data source from Oracle and SQL Server to Quickbooks and Salesforce. Requirements include:

   - Azure SQL Server ODBC Driver or a previously created [Data Source Name (DSN)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/administer-odbc-data-sources-b19f856b-5b9b-48c9-8b93-07484bfab5a7)
   - Ensure connected user has read/write table privileges (assign on the server)
   - Walk through wizard for initial setup (see ODBC database option under External Data)

   [image]
2. Action Queries

   **SQL** *(save as an MS Access stored query, can double click object to run manually)*

   Number of columns should be equivalent in `INSERT` and `SELECT` clauses and each corresponding type should match (leave out autonumbers).

   ```
   INSERT INTO mySQLServerTable (Col1, Col2, Col3, ...)
   SELECT e.Col1, e.Col2, e.Col3, ...
   FROM myExcelTable AS e
   ```

   Alternatively, if you need to run an `UPDATE` query requiring match column(s) between the two table sources.

   ```
   UPDATE mySQLServerTable s
   INNER JOIN myExceltable e ON e.MatchColumn = s.MatchColumn
   SET s.Col1 = e.Col1, s.Col2 = e.Col2, s.Col3 = e.Col3, ...
   ```

   **VBA** *(automatic run of stored query inside MS Access)*

   ```vb
   ' WARNS USER OF NUMEBR OF ROWS TO BE INSERTED/UPDATED
   DoCmd.OpenQuery "myActionQuery"

   ' DOES NOT WARN USER
   CurrentDb.Execute "myActionQuery", dbFailOnError
   ```

---

Conversely, you can run an SQL Server query that inserts into your table from the external MS Access source using [OPENROWSET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). This assumes the database is accessibly from where the SQL Server resides.

```
INSERT INTO INSERT INTO mySQLServerTable (Col1, Col2, Col3, ...)
SELECT e.Col1, e.Col2, e.Col3, ... 
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
                'C:\path\to\myDatabase.accdb', 'admin', '', myExcelTable) AS e
```